# OData Web API routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, odata, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a web API exposing ODATA from a SQL stored proc.  I want to use a url like /odata/firmhierarchy(225) to pass 225 into a param for the stored proc.  It just tells me that it can't find a matching resource.  It hits the controller, just skips the method.  Thoughts?

In webapiconfig

```
        private static IEdmModel GenerateEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employees");
        builder.EntitySet<Employee>("FirmHierarchy");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

Context:

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<Employee> sp_EmployeeHierarchy(Nullable<int> managerEmpID)
    {
        var managerEmpIDParameter = managerEmpID.HasValue ?
            new SqlParameter("ManagerEmpID", managerEmpID) :
            new SqlParameter("ManagerEmpID", 0);

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Employee>("sp_EmployeeHierarchy @ManagerEmpID", managerEmpIDParameter);
    }
```

Only method in controller:

```
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Employee> GetFirmHierarchy()
    {
        return db.sp_EmployeeHierarchy(225).AsQueryable();
        //return SingleResult.Create(db.Employees.Where(employee => employee.EmpId == key));
    }
```

Comment: Is it your problem that you can't pass 225 from the request URL to the controller method?

Comment: Yes, that's my issue.  I bailed and flattened the table to a view and just did it that way.  But I'd like to find out how I could have called the sp, with a param....passing it through with odata.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

1.Write another method in your controller:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Employee> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return db.sp_EmployeeHierarchy(key).AsQueryable();
}
```

Please note that `[EnableQuery]` is an attribute introduced in Web API for OData V4. If you are still using Web API for OData V1-3, use `[Queryable]` still.

2.Then you can send the request

```
GET /odata/firmhierarchy(225)
```

and get the employees.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make ODATA work for a table, when auto-generated from entity framework.  However, that generation process didn't want to work for a complex type returned by a Table Valued Function (similar scenario to a SP), because it didn't seem to understand where the key was.

What I found was that I could however make it work.  First, I check out this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/expose-odata-endpoint-without-entity-framework-and-perform-c/).  He sets things up a bit more manually, where his **Get** on a **companyProcessing**Controller ends up routing for id 3 as "http://localhost:10020/odata/**companyProcessing**(3)" .

This surprised me.  My other generated classes set up the pattern that SomeEntity became SomeEntityController, with methods like GetSomeEntities, and a routing that seemed to me to match the method but dropping the word get.  Therefore, dropping the entity name from the Get method name seemed different, but it worked.  Proving that the path is actually matching the controller name, not the method name.

In this Case you configure the routing using the data type you're querying for, and the beginning of the controller name.  Then the actual path utilizes the beginning of the controller name as well.

And then all of this just brings us essentially to the other posted solution, assuming your controller name is **firmhierarchy**Controller

So, now, making sense of this...  Try going to http://localhost:55063/odata/$metadata , where your port may differ.  You'll notice that ODATA exposes a **DataType**, which is accessed via a **DataSet**.  When a client tries to query into ODATA, they are trying to query against the DataSet, getting items of the DataType.

The DataSet matching the controller name (less Controller), and the Get methods can indeed just be Get without further extension of the name - and otherwise in this scenario was giving me problems.